# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los números menores que 5 de un arreglo en Swift?

Tags: array, swift

Mi arreglo es este:

```
let numbers = [ 3,6,9,2,4,1 ]
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener los números menores que 5 de un arreglo en Swift?
Intento usar esto

```
    let numbers = [3,6,9,2,4,1]
     var minNumber = 5
     for number in numbers {
      minNumber = min (minNumber,number as Int)
}     
        print("Los numeros menores son:\(minNumber)")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero solo me da un número y necesito como 1, 2, 3, 4 No sé si debería ordenar el arreglo primero o si debería buscar el número. Lo siento si es una pregunta tonta, pero estoy aprendiendo.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, realmente lo agradecería

Comment: El código va como texto y estás en SO en español, traduce la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes almacenar los números en otro array e insertarlos cuando cumplen la condición. El nuevo array sería:

```
var resultado: [Int] = []
```

Entonces el código completo quedaría así:

```
let numbers = [3,6,9,2,4,1]
var minNumber = 5
var resultado: [Int] = []//Aquí almacenas los números del resultado de validar la condición.

for number in numbers {
      if number < miNumber {//Verificas si cumple la condición
          resultado.append(number)//Agregas el número al array resultado.
      }
}     

print("Los numeros menores son:\(resultado)")//Imprimes el array resultado [3, 2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el ejemplo, me ha sacado de un gran problema

Answer (score 0):

```
    //  usa: numbers.filter({$0<5})

    let numbers = [3,6,9,2,4,1]
    let minNumber = numbers.filter({$0<5})
    print("Los numeros menores son:\(minNumber)")
```

Comment: Las respuestas de sólo código no ***ayudan*** a nadie puesto que copiar y pegar no sirve para *aprender*. Te recomiendo que añadas una explicación de qué hace tu código, sobre todo la parte `numbers.filter({$0<5})`, que es fácil que alguien con pocos conocimientos no entienda nada de lo que está pasando ahí. Te recomiendo además leer [answer] y hacer el [tour] para entender cómo funciona SO.